# An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2012, c++-cli

Okay so, I'm programming a Yachzee game, and well, it's not working perticulary well.

When I click the button "Roll" this code is started.

```
         int rand1 = rand()%6+1;
         int rand2 = rand()%6+1;
         int rand3 = rand()%6+1;
         int rand4 = rand()%6+1;
         int rand5 = rand()%6+1;

         Dice^ t1 = gcnew Dice (rand1);
         Dice^ t2 = gcnew Dice (rand2);
         Dice^ t3 = gcnew Dice (rand3);
         Dice^ t4 = gcnew Dice (rand4);
         Dice^ t5 = gcnew Dice (rand5);
```

It creates five seperate random numbers and send them to my Dice.h as five seperate objects.

This is the code in Dice.h

```
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;

ref class Dice {

public:
    Dice (int rand)
    {
        this->rand = rand;
        createPictureBox();
    }

private:
    int rand;
    PictureBox^ p;

public:
void createPictureBox()
{
        //PictureBox^ p = gcnew PictureBox();

        p->Size = System::Drawing::Size(91, 85);
        if ( rand == 1 )
            p->ImageLocation = "..\\Bilder\\dice_face_1.png";
        else if ( rand == 2 )
            p->ImageLocation = "..\\Bilder\\dice_face_2.png";
        else if ( rand == 3 )
            p->ImageLocation = "..\\Bilder\\dice_face_3.png";
        else if ( rand == 4 )
            p->ImageLocation = "..\\Bilder\\dice_face_4.png";
        else if ( rand == 5 )
            p->ImageLocation = "..\\Bilder\\dice_face_5.png";
        else
            p->ImageLocation = "..\\Bilder\\dice_face_6.png";
        p->SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode::StretchImage;
}

public:
PictureBox^ getPictureBox()
{
    return p;
}

int getRand()
{
    return rand;
}

};
```

As it is now, the program breaks with an arrow pointing to the row which says

```
p->ImageLocation = "..\\Bilder\\dice_face_1.png";
```

And if I move the row which says

```
p->Size = System::Drawing::Size(91, 85);
```

under the else, where the row changing the SizeMode is it will break with a arrow pointing to the if, else if, or else which have the number corresponding to the value of rand. And if I look below where it seems to show all the different values of variables it will show this

```
Name    |   Value                                       |   Type
_________________________________________________________________

this    |   0x02b6e9a4 { rand=1 p=<undefined value> }   |   Dice^
```

Last thing to add is that it says the following in the break pop up

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: You don't allocate the `PictureBox`. It's just a `null` variable. You can't set the `Size` on a `null`, it just *won't work.* You need to create an instance of the `PictureBox` first. `PictureBox^ p = new PictureBox();` or similar. (I can't remember the exact syntax.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: I see no c# code nor C++ code here, only C++/CLI with Windows Forms. I have updated the tags to replace this. Also, if you are going to be using C++/CLI, I would suggest that you use [.Net Random](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of the C library `rand()`.

Comment: @EBrown - Is that something that is done on the line I commented away? (The first one in the createPictureBox function) If not, how is that done?

Comment: @Trisstar Yes. That is where it should be done.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an instance of the PictureBox control and add it as a child to the form or a container control.

Comment: Is that something that is done on the line I commented away? (The first one in the createPictureBox function)

If not, how is that done?

Comment: Partially yes ... don't forget the adding of the control to the form hierarchy.

Comment: An alternate solution is to reuse an existing picture box control already on the form.  A fixed number of dice probably makes more sense to reuse existing controls.

Answer (score 0):

While running the program, Exception Settings pane will be visible at the bottom of the vs. Open it then type NullReferenceException in the search box and check the System.NullReferenceException box.